# How to add createAt field into Mongodb using _id as timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a user collection with already existed of 200 data and i forgot to set createAt field in schema

now i want to update all the existed field and add into database using (`_id`) which is already a timestamp

so all i want is a query which take the _id and convert into date and save into existed data (i am using robo 3T )

please sorry if i have asked silly question. I am new to mongodb

Comment: Please share collection at jsoneditor online

Comment: why you need a collection?  all i want is to add a field into collection. so collection can be anything.

Comment: which Mongo version are you using?

Comment: 4.2.0 @tomslabbaert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is robo mongo query, it won't work in mongo console.

```
db.getCollection('collectionNameGoesHere').find({}, {
    _id: 1
}).forEach(function (doc) {
    db.getCollection('collectionNameGoesHere').update({
        _id: doc._id
    }, {
        $set: {
            createdAt: doc._id.getTimestamp()
        }
    }, {
        upsert: false,
        multi: true
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these two queries to create the `createdAt` field with the date/timestamp from `_id`. The first one works MongoDb version 4.0+ and the second with MongoDB version 4.2.

Note these work in *Mongo Shell*, and not tested in *robo3T*.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $project: { createdAt: { $toDate: "$_id" } } 
  }
] ).forEach( doc => db.test.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { createdAt: doc.createdAt } } ) )


db.test.updateMany(
  { },
  [
      { $set: { createdAt: { $toDate: "$_id" } } }
  ]
)
```