# How to update column with two date difference in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update the collection with some new added columns. The new columns value will be based on the two date type difference in an array on the same document. For example, the following are the sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd289a93f7cf02c36837ca7"),
    "ClientName" : "John",
    "OrderNumber" : "12345A",
    "Type1OrderTurnAroundDays" : 0,
    "Type2OrderTurnAroundDays" : 0,
    "OrderDetail" : [ 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type1OrderDate",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-02-20T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "Note" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type1PackDate",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-03-04T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "Note" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type2OrderDate",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-01-04T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "Note" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type2PackDate",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-04-15T05:00:00.000Z"),
            "Note" : ""
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd289a93f7cf02c36837ca9"),
    "ClientName" : "Mary",
    "OrderNumber" : "12345C",
    "Type1OrderTurnAroundDays" : 0,
    "Type2OrderTurnAroundDays" : 0,
    "OrderDetail" : [ 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type1OrderDate",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-01-20T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "Note" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type1PackDate",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-02-04T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "Note" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type2OrderDate",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-01-04T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "Note" : ""
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd289a93f7cf02c36827ca7"),
    "ClientName" : "Kate",
    "OrderNumber" : "12345B",
    "Type1OrderTurnAroundDays" : 0,
    "Type2OrderTurnAroundDays" : 0,
    "OrderDetail" : [ 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type2OrderDate",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-02-02T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "Note" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type2PackDate",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-03-15T05:00:00.000Z"),
            "Note" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

So I want to update the column `Type1OrderTurnAroundDays` with the subtraction between "dateOfOrder" with the "OrderDesc" as "Type1OrderDate" and "dateOfOrder" with the "OrderDesc" as "Type1PackDate" and the same logic with `Type2OrderTurnAroundDays` with subtraction from "dateOfOrder" with the "OrderDesc" as "Type2OrderDate" and "dateOfOrder" with the "OrderDesc" as "Type2PackDate". When there is no date value in the array, the number will be consider as 0 instead.

So I want to use `db.test.updateMany({}, {$set:{"Type1OrderTurnAroundDays": {$subtract:["",""]}}})` type of logic but have a hard time to put the logic inside the $subtract together using aggregate to $unwind the arrary value and do the calculation. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Use [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to update based upon multiple document fields.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My current DB is on 3.6 version and looks like update with aggregation pipeline will only work for Mongo 4.2 and above. In SQL server I could use cursor to loop through and update the column using the calculation. Is there anything available in Mongo DB sort of like the same thing? Is it even feasible to run update query in mongo to fulfill this ?

Comment: Yes, you can use an aggregation query to transform the document, and then loop over the resulting cursor. Within the loop you can perform updates on each document. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471191/how-to-add-createat-field-into-mongodb-using-id-as-timestamp/59476169#59476169

Comment: Thanks. Can I declare variables like SQL and do complicate calculation and then do the subtraction? Like here, I need to declare the $Type1orderDate  when type is Type1OrderDate and $Type1PackDate when type is Type1PackDate and then use subtraction to find out the difference from the two variables and then update ..

Comment: You can do your calculations within aggregation itself, or in your for loop.

Comment: I am using Mongo 3.6 so looks like update using aggregation is for 4.2.So I might be able to use this format: 
db.getCollection('test').find({}, {
    _id: 1
}).forEach(function (doc) {
    db.getCollection('test').update({
        _id: doc._id
    }, {
        $set: {
           "Type1OrderTurnAroundDays": {$subtract:["$Type1OrderDate","$Type1PackDate"]}}})
        }
    }, {
        upsert: false,
        multi: true
    })
});

But the $Type1OrderDate and $Type1PackDate are based on the different type. How can I get those fit in the query above? I am totally blank here.

Comment: `{$subtract:["$Type1OrderDate","$Type1PackDate"]}` - this will work within aggregate or update with aggregate only.

Comment: Can you be more specific how to use update with aggregate for this work. Do I still need to loop through each document to do the update?